# obtener el ultimo arreglo asociativo bidimensional

Tags: php

Hola necesito obtener el ultimo  arreglo asociativo bidimensional pero no se como  recorrer  cada elemento de la primera dimensión, y hacerle  "end() para obtener el ultimo registro de cada uno.

Es según "time" debo extraer el ultimo y dejarlos en un array nuevo.

**lo que quiero hacer es obtener el ultimo mensaje de cada numero ("author"). obtener el ultimo con "time"**

```
$url = 'http://gnex.cl/ajax/json.json';

$result = file_get_contents($url); // Send a request
$data = json_decode($result, 1); // Parse JSON

$agrupados = array();

foreach($data['messages'] as $currmsg)
{
    if (!isset($agrupados[$currmsg['author']]))
        {
            $agrupados[$currmsg['author']] = array();
        }

    array_push($agrupados[$currmsg['author']], $currmsg);
}
```

**ACA TENGO EL PROBLEMA DE COMO IMPLEMENTAR END Y AGREGAR A $hola = array()**

```
$hola = array();

foreach ($agrupados as $key => $value) {

    print $key."<p>";

    foreach ($value as $key => $value_1) {

        foreach ($value_1 as $key_1 ) {

            //if($key_1['author']){

                array_push(end($hola[$value_1['time']]), $value);
            //}
            # code...
        }



    }
```

Comment: En esta línea *array_push(end($hola[$value_1['time']]), $value);* ¿no sería así? array_push(end($hola[$key]['time']), $value); En realidad, sin ver un var_dump de $agrupados no sabría decirte, pero en esa línea algo está mal, seguro.

Comment: A ver si entiendo mejor, vos querés reestructurar el array para que esté ordenado por el key `time` y agrupados por `author`?

Comment: ya esta agrupados por author en el primer foreach.  quiero reestructurar el array para dejar solo el ultimo mensaje por medio de time.

Comment: Claro, quieres que en ese agrupamiento de `author` sólo quede el último mensaje (ordenado por `time` descendentemente).

Comment: si eso necesito solo obtener el ultimo mensaje de cada author. como lo podria hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es sólo en el primer `foreach` un `end()` pero de los mensajes, ya que están ordenados.

```
$url = 'http://gnex.cl/ajax/json.json';
$result = file_get_contents($url); // Send a request
$data = json_decode($result, true); // Parse JSON

$agrupados = array();

foreach($data['messages'] as $currmsg) {
    if (!isset($agrupados[$currmsg['author']])) {
        $agrupados[$currmsg['author']] = array();
    }

    array_push($agrupados[$currmsg['author']], $currmsg);
}

$hola = array();

foreach ($agrupados as $author => $messages) {
    array_push($hola, end($messages));
}
```

Y al hacer un `var_dump($hola)` va a generar el siguiente **output**:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(42) "true_56968704213@c.us_3EB0022131448222E23A"
    ["body"]=>
    string(5) "okale"
    ["fromMe"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["author"]=>
    string(16) "56983684579@c.us"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1525275551)
    ["chatId"]=>
    string(16) "56968704213@c.us"
    ["messageNumber"]=>
    int(185)
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "chat"
    ["senderName"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(43) "false_56968704213@c.us_3EB08C084679FE808DDC"
    ["body"]=>
    string(7) "de todo"
    ["fromMe"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["author"]=>
    string(16) "56968704213@c.us"
    ["time"]=>
    int(1525270853)
    ["chatId"]=>
    string(16) "56968704213@c.us"
    ["messageNumber"]=>
    int(199)
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "chat"
    ["senderName"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
  }
}
```

Comment: oo gracias amigo. muchas gracias por tu tiempo. agradecido desde Chile.

Comment: Si te fue de ayuda, no olvides de marcar como correcta la respuesta.

Comment: ultima consulta, dentro de end se puede colocar alguna condición. por que?. Dentro del array hay un campo "fromMe" que es true o false. esto es para saber si es saliente o entrante el mensaje. solo me interesa el ultimo mensaje entrante que es true. como lo podría hacer?

Comment: es asi cierto? if($currmsg['fromMe'] == true){
  
  array_push($agrupados[$currmsg['chatId']], $currmsg);
 }

Comment: No, porque en ese caso toma siempre el último en el `if`, es posible que necesites usar `usort()` de PHP y pasarle una función para validar eso.